# Exception propagation between two functions in python

Tags: python, exception, design-patterns

I have a simple best practice question. The setting is that i simply have one function calling another one. The code ist little dummy for better understanding:

```
def called_function(x):
    y = x * 3
    try:
        z = 3 / x
    except my_crazy_exception as e: 
        print("I want at least to know y!")
        print(y)
        # Does this make sense:
        # ??? raise my_crazy_exception ????

if __name__ == "main":
    for i in my_crazy_list:
        try:
            called_function(i)
        except my_crazy_exception as e:
            print("I want to know i!")
            print(i)
```

Know i want to know information from the called function and as well from the calling function. So i want to pass the exception from the origin to the next higher function. My idea would be know just to raise another excepterin in the `except:` part of the called function. But would this be best practice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Exception Propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891572/python-exception-propagation)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't actually care about the cause of the exception, you can just return optionals :

```py
from typing import Tuple, Optional


def function_one(x) -> Tuple[int, Optional[int]]:
    #                        y  , z
    y = x*3
    try:
        z = 3/x
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        # at least return Y
        return y, None
    else:
        # everything went fine, return both
        return y, z


def function_two(x) -> Tuple[int, int, Optional[int]]:
    #                        x  , y,   z
    y, maybe_z = function_one(x=x)
    return x, y, maybe_z


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(3):
        x, y, z = function_two(x=i)
        print(f"i=x={i} y={y} z={z}")
```

outputs

```
i=x=0 y=0 z=None
i=x=1 y=3 z=3.0
i=x=2 y=6 z=1.5
```

Exceptions are harder to handle than optionals in return types in my opinion. It is easy to forget to catch the exception, to catch the wrong class, to forget to re-raise it, ... Return typing can be easily checked by tool, and visually indicated by IDEs. Because I value the principle of "least astonishment", I would then consider returning an optional a better practice than raising an exception in this case.

But if the architecture of your actual code is much more complex than the example (for example a deep call stack, third-party integration, ...), it may be justified to use exceptions. In that very case, something like that would do:

```py
class ThereWasAnErrorButYouCanHaveThisYValue(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg, y):
        super().__init__(msg)
        self.y = y


def unreliable_function(x):
    y = x*3
    try:
        z = 3/x
    except ZeroDivisionError as err:
        raise ThereWasAnErrorButYouCanHaveThisYValue(str(err), y)
    else:
        return y, z


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(3):
        try:
            y, z = unreliable_function(x=i)
        except ThereWasAnErrorButYouCanHaveThisYValue as err:
            print(f"error {str(err)}, but i=x={i} y={err.y}")
        else:
            print(f"ok: i=x={i} y={y} z={z}")
```

outputs

```
error division by zero, but i=x=0 y=0
ok: i=x=1 y=3 z=3.0
ok: i=x=2 y=6 z=1.5
```

Comment: Another thing to consider is : can you separate the computation of Y from the computation of Z ? If so, you can have two functions, the first one always returning an Y, the second one that may return a Z but that you must handle carefully (either raising an exception or returning an error value like None), which completely bypasses your problem of surfacing Y when there is an error computing Z (an instance of a [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)).